# Closest value (MS Access)

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, max, formula

Is it possible to get closest(smaller) value of the same id in MS Access database? 
It only need one expression, but I don't know how to write it properly.
Should looks like this:

```
ID     Value     Value2
1        10         0
2        5          0
1        20         10
1        50         20
2        15         5
...and so on..........
```

I have tried to use Dlookup and Max functions but I failed.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Your expected output???

Comment: @DineshDB Columns "ID" and "Value" are given. Trying to get values in column "Value2" by formula.

Comment: I do not know what you mean when you say closest.  Gordon's answer below assumes you mean 'previous'.  But even previous is not well defined.  What is the order of the result set?  What fields are used to determine the 'previous' record?

Comment: You appear to want the previous value for the same id.  You need a column that specifies the ordering of the rows in the table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so a column has to contain the ordering information.

Comment: @EllieK  , Gordon-Linoff...  OK, if I just add one more column called "Number" which  will specifies the ordering of my table. How can I get the right value?   P.S. Sorry, I'm new in SQL, that is why can't cope with such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the *previous* value.  There is no way to do this unless you have a column specifying the ordering.  If so:

```
select t.*,
       (select top (1) t2.value
        from t as t2
        where t2.? < t.?
        order by t2.? desc
       ) as prev_value
from t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: unfortunately still can't handle this... Can You please show me an example using my parameter, if it is possible. I have table called "records" , columns inside it: "number"- ordering element; "car"; "KM" - value. And need new column "prev_KM" which will show one record smaller value of "KM" of particular "car"